# Alphabetically sorting an array piece by piece

Tags: c++, sorting, character-arrays

I'm trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically that have the same frequency from the input file. I start by looping through the entire array, and set the indices at the points where the group of words have the same frequencies. Then I insertion sort between the given indices. Here's the function:

```
//Insertion sort up the array, checking for same frequencies and moving words alphabetically downwards
int startIdx = 0;
int endIdx = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < freq.length(); k++) {
    if(freq.at(startIdx) == freq.at(k)) {
        endIdx++;
    }
    else { 
        insertionSort(startIdx, endIdx); //Sort the string array at the given indices
        startIdx = endIdx = k;
    }
}
```

The function isn't sorting the array...it works when the indices are set to 0 to length(), or some other arbitrarily set values but otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: You're trying to sort an array of integers alphabetically? Could you try to rephrase your question? As it currently stands it isn't very clear.

Comment: Sounds like you are sorting on a copy, not the original. What does your debugger show you?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, I meant to say strings. The integer array goes side-by-side with the cstring array. Edited for clarity.

I'm editing the original array as it stands. The debugger shows me where the sort begins on the indices in the group, and gives me the addresses of the pointers. words.setAt() works to swap the elements in the string array.

Comment: @TaylorBishop Is it your homework to implement the sorting algo or can you use `std::sort`?

Comment: So your debugger shows you the **swapped** values in place after `the words.setAt()` sequence? If so, then you are not displaying the same array as you are swapping on. Make sure the array you are sorting on, and the array you are displaying after all this work as your final results, are actually the same array. The reason is that if the values are being swapped as the debugger shows, then they'd be swapped outside this function--- if they are the same array. Otherwise: it is a copy.

Comment: It doesn't. My setAt() function only changes where the char* pointer at the specified location is pointing to, could that have something to do with it?

I just noticed that it does correctly swap some of the elements in a group alphabetically, but it seems completely random.